# With OS X , is there a way to create a 640 x 640 image out of a 500 x 640 image?

Tags: macos, mac, photos, photos.app

Some website requires the user to "crop" the photo, but sometimes you'd like to keep it original.

Using OS X alone, can a a 500 x 640 photo be enlarged to 640 x 640 (with white or black bars at the left and right), without installing additional apps?  (this can be viewed as, creating a 640 x 640 black image, and the pasting the 500 x 640 photo onto it).

Comment: Open it in Preview and take a screenshot?

Comment: that might work (you can set the background color in Preview). Except then you have to crop out the image region and make sure it is exactly 640 x 640?  also it seems a little bit hacky

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `sips` command to pad any JPEG or BMP image to a specified size, with a specified colour. In your case, the command would look something like:

```
sips photo-500x640.jpg --padToHeightWidth 640 640 --padColor 000000 --out photo-640x640.jpg
```

obviously with the input and output filenames of your choice. For white instead of black borders, change 000000 to FFFFFF.

Comment: it works perfect

Comment: Just curious: can you configure a transparent --padColor?

Comment: Don't think there's a way to specify that, but it used to be that if you tried to pad a PNG, it would pad with transparency regardless of the colour you specified. Haven't tried recently to see if that's still the case.